# How to rename file names that are too long that Windows won't allow me to rename via F2?

Tags: windows, rename, filenames

I've downloaded some journal papers where the default name for the PDFs are too long. Windows won't allow me to open the files, let alone rename them by pressing F2.

How do i rename these PDF files so i can actually do something with them?

I had quite a number of journals that wouldn't copy to a new location because of the length of the filenames. I attempted to use [Rename Master](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/) to rename all of the files but 27 have resisted the program renaming them. Which is when i discovered that i couldn't open them or rename them using F2.

Thanks

Comment: the solution that i found to move them is to zip them after that Copy/Paste

Comment: It seems unlikely the default file names are too long.  All Windows versions since at least Win2000 support file/path names of up to 260 characters and newer versions allow even longer names

Comment: @JJF You can get long files names.

Comment: Try Windows Explorer

Comment: @Yagami Light - Thank you! You're a life saver!

Comment: @JJF Very long file name + directory can exceed the allowed limit on the number characters.

Comment: I came across a similar problem and using 7-zip(a third-party software) helped me.

- Install 7-zip [https://www.7-zip.org/][1]
- Open "7-zip File Manager"
- Using it, navigate to your folder and change the name of the file/folder you want to delete into a simple one.
- Delete the file/folder with Shift + Del (which might save you from facing the same problem at the Recycle Bin, which might fail again)

  [1]: https://www.7-zip.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that i found to resolve this problem is to use zip, you only have to zip them and after that you can `Copy/Paste` them where ever you want, hope that helped you.

**Update 3/1/2022**
7zip will let you rename the file without creating an archive.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that i found would work is what Yagami Light suggested.

I zipped the entire folder with the files that had the stupidly long file names. I moved it to the root directory. Unzipped the files and Windows allowed me to edit the file names.

Windows wouldn't allow me to zip the individual files hence why i zipped the entire folder.

Thanks Yagami

Comment: will be better for me if i make it an answer an you will mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Yeah sure. I have no problem with that. :)

Comment: Really i am impressed (in the positive why )